# recursive method to find a digit that occur in given number

Tags: java

```
public static int countDigitx(int n, int x) {
    int count = 0;

    if (n == 0) {
        count = 1;
    } else if (n%10 == x) {
        count++;
        countDigitx(n+1,x);
    }
    return count;
}
```

i'm trying to do but i feel this isn't the correct way that i'm doing.
because i think my logic isn't correct to find digit at each index.for example if n=23432 and x=4 so the output should be 1.

Comment: `i feel this isn't the correct way that i'm doing.` **Why?**

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your function is title `countDigits` but your question title asks about finding digits within a number.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: i felt so because my output isnt coming correct sotirios

Comment: the question is to find the number of times that digit occur like if number is 54352 and x=5 then it should display that 5 occurs 2 times

Comment: There are a few major things wrong with your code.  When you call the method again, you need to precede with a `return` statement (same with your base case).  Also, you pass `n+1`...which should be `n/10`.  Try doing a paper/pencil run through of your code...you'll start to see what's wrong

Comment: `count` should be `0` when `n==0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm that you are using is wrong, this is the change that you need :

```
 public static int countDigitx(int n, int x) {
        int count = 0;

        if (n == 0) {
            count = 0;
        } else if (n%10 == x) {
            count++;
          count += countDigitx(n/10,x);
        } else {
           count += countDigitx(n/10,x);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

**Reason :** once you check whether the last digit of the number is equal to the target digit (x), you need to divide the number by 10 so that then you can check the next digit and so on and so forth. Also you need to accumulate the counts from the recursive call.

Comment: Thnxx alot ur code ws helpful

Answer (score 0):

You've got three very bad problems.

- You don't use the result of the recursive method call, so you're not actually accumulating any count.
- You only call the method in the case where the last digit is `x`.  That call should not be inside that `else if` block.
- You're adding 1 to `n` for no apparent reason, which will change the answer completely.  You should be dividing by 10 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one working recursive solution,

```
public static int countDigitx(int n, int x) {
    int count = 0;
    String s = String.valueOf(n); // make n a String.
    if (s != null && s.length() > 0) { // Check for not empty
        String ch = String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)); // String valueOf 1st char
        if (x == Integer.parseInt(ch)) { // Compare the int values
            count++; // Add one to the count.
        }
        s = s.substring(1); // substring from 1.
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            count += countDigitx(Integer.parseInt(s), x); // add recursive result
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countDigitx(23432, 4)); // test
    System.out.println(countDigitx(555, 5)); // test2
}
```

Output is

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal if I understand correctly is to count how many times the number 'x' is present in your number 'n'. Your recursive call `countDigitx(n+1,x)` should be `countDigitx(n/10,x)`. Try to think of a better base case. Think of what will happen when you send in `n = 1100` and `x = 1`...

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the function so that it took a string input instead of a int, much easier to manipulate.  If you can't do that, I'd use a helper function (shown):

```
public static int countDigitx(int n, int x) { // this is the helper
       return countDigitString(Integer.toString(n), Integer.toString(x));
}

public static int countDigitString(String n, String x){  // this is the recursive function
    if (!n.contains(x))
        return 0;
    return (1 + countDigitString(n.substring(n.indexOf(x) , n.length()) , x)
}
```